# пройти по списку ul и сохранить значение li js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Существует тег `ul` с рандомным количеством элементов `li`, в каждом `li` лежит `input` с `checkbox`-ом и со своим индивидуальным значением, нужно с помощью `jQuery` реализовать функцию которая проходя по всем `li` будет сохранять значения тех которые помечены галочкой и сохранить все значения в массив, подскажите пожалуйста.
Вот что нагуглил чтобы ходит по `ul`, значение выводит, а сохранять не получается...

```
  function create() {
      $('#checked input:checkbox:checked').each(function() {
          var ert = $(this).val();
          alert(ert);
      });
  }
```

Comment: плохая идея изначально, не стоит из дома создавать данные нужно из данных строить дом

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно создать массив и добавлять в него значения в виде объекта.

```
function create() {
  var arrCheck = [];
  $('#checked input:checkbox:checked').each(function(idx, item) {
    var ert = {
      val: $(this, item).val()
    };
    arrCheck.push(ert);
  });
  console.log(arrCheck);
}
```